Impulse response for a VECM
I have used MatLAB for calculating generalized impulse response functions (see https://se.mathworks.com/help/econ/vecm.irf.html#mw_ef2bb791-5500-4738-b2de-49df99f3a990_sep_shared-mw_85c3ba24-ff12-4a90-b585-838dc341359a)
However, whenever I calculate the irfs, the bootstrapped confidensintervals (2000 rep) sort of diverge.
Does anyone know why this is the case?
Thanks in advance
